# Making an int value of 100 change throughout the code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game2 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Scanner bri = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        int roll1 = 1 + r.nextInt(6);
        int roll2 = 1 + r.nextInt(6);
        int rsum = roll1+roll2;
        int bal = 100;
        int bet;
        String wager;

        System.out.println("High n' Low");
        System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Your balance is: "+bal+" $");
        do
        {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit): ");
        bet = bri.nextInt();

        if (bet > bal)
        {
            System.out.println("You don't have that much money Try again.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (bet == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Place a wager. High, Low or Sevens? (H/L/S): ");
        wager = bri.next();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Roll #1: "+roll1);
        System.out.println("Roll #2: "+roll2);
        System.out.println("Roll Total: "+rsum);    

        if (wager.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
        {
        if (rsum >= 8)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You win! Your new balance: "+(bet*1+bal)+"$");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You lost! Your new balance: "+(bal-bet)+"$");
        }
        }
        if (wager.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
        {
        if (rsum <= 8)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You win! Your new balance: "+(bet*1+bal)+"$");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You lost! Your new balance: "+(bal-bet)+"$");
        }
        }
        if (wager.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        {
        if (rsum == 7)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You win! Your new balance: "+(bet*4+bal)+"$");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You lost! Your new balance: "+(bal-bet)+"$");
        }
        if (bal <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("You're out of money, goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        }
        }while (bal > 1);



}
}
```

I am looking to have int bal = 100 change and keep a persistently changing value when I have my if statements calculate the new balance. But it seems to keep reverting back to the value of 100 after going through a loop.

Comment: You never change `bal` in the code you posted.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format your code readably, with sensible indentation and such. You can do whatever you like in your own code, but when other people have to read it, make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not changing value of bal variable anywhere...you are only printing the calculated value just assign it to bal

```
  if (wager.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
            {
            if (rsum >= 8)
            {

                System.out.println("");
//assign it as and then print it
    bal =(bet*1+bal)
                System.out.println("You win! Your new balance: "+bal +"$");
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know it was as simple as that, but appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def validHeight(cm):
    try:
        cm = float(cm)
        return 100 <= cm <= 250
    except ValueError:
        return False

>>> validHeight(190)
True
>>> validHeight('190')
True
>>> validHeight('')
False
>>> validHeight('190.0')
True
```

Comment: and select code and press CTRL+K to format code before answering.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
do
{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit): ");
    bet = bri.nextInt();

    if (bet > bal)
    {
        System.out.println("You don't have that much money Try again.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (bet == 0)
    {
         System.out.println("Goodbye!");
         System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Place a wager. High, Low or Sevens? (H/L/S): ");
    wager = bri.next();

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Roll #1: "+roll1);
    System.out.println("Roll #2: "+roll2);
    System.out.println("Roll Total: "+rsum);    

    if (wager.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
    {
        if (rsum >= 8)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You win! Your new balance: "+(bet*1+bal)+"$");
            bal = bet*1 + bal;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You lost! Your new balance: "+(bal-bet)+"$");
            bal = bal - bet;
        }
    }
    if (wager.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
    {
        if (rsum <= 8)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You win! Your new balance: "+(bet*1+bal)+"$");
            bal = bet*1 + bal;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You lost! Your new balance: "+(bal-bet)+"$");
            bal = bal - bet;
        }
    }
    if (wager.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
    {
        if (rsum == 7)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You win! Your new balance: "+(bet*4+bal)+"$");
            bal = bet*4 + bal;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You lost! Your new balance: "+(bal-bet)+"$");
            bal = bal - bet;
        }
        if (bal <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("You're out of money, goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}while (bal > 1);
```